# How to get the result of table contains numeric and strings using where condition

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.5

I have a table like below

[image]

If I select item_no>'1623' from above table

I want to print the result below

```
1666
1674
1912
1952
1953
```

I am trying below command

```
select * from table where item_no>'1623'
```

But it's giving wrong result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `SUBSTRING`

```
select * from t where substring(item_no,'([0-9]+)') :: int  > 1623
```

[**DEMO**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=90790b7325fdc025c9e8ff3091d1cc67)

Comment: thanks its worked. and if i select item-no>1623G  can i get the result 1623H and 1623I and remaining values

Answer (score 1):

Just try to cast `item_no` as integer ( I suppose it's non-numeric ).

```
with tab(numbers) as
(
 select nullif(left(item_no, strpos(item_no, '_') - 1),'')::integer from "table"    
)    
select numbers
  from tab
 where numbers > 1623
```

( without seeing the picture, considering the comment *all of the data end with a non-numeric character* ) all data composed of digits upto the last character.

Or, try to extract the digits only as :

```
with tab(numbers) as
(
 select nullif(regexp_replace(col, '\D','','g'),'')::integer from "table"    
)    
select numbers
  from tab
 where numbers > 1623
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://rextester.com/FAO74966)</kbd>

Comment: getting below error ERROR:  invalid input syntax for integer: "1623G"
********** Error **********

ERROR: invalid input syntax for integer: "1623G"
SQL state: 22P02

Comment: @joe please share a text that picture I cannot see it. Btw, 1623G is not numeric of course. Do all data end with a `G` character ?